# Is it possible to convert CustomObject[] to String[] without iteration?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom object:

```
public class Cat {
    private String mName;
    private int mAge;

    public Cat(String name, int age) {
        mName = name;
        mAge = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

I need to get String[] with names from Cat[]. It it possible? How to get it?

Comment: You will need to iterate, one way or another...

Comment: I think without iterating it is not possible specially when you are only using `toString( )`method. Even you write a method by yourself to do this you may need to iterate the array by yourself.

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't want to iterate through because your question title suggests that you knew it would be possible with interaction?

Answer (score 1):

As *assylias*  wrote in the comments - you *will* iterate it one way or another, that said, if you don't want to *explicitly* iterate it - you can use [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
Cat[] catArray = ...
String catArrayStr = Arrays.toString(catArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Google Guava's `transform`, which is lazily evaluated, thus only iterating once when it's used.